# rails authorization by using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm newbie on rails so sorry in advance if this question is very basic.
I have 2 main entities on my test application.

- project
- user

each user has many projects relationship. 
There are 2 types of project (public and private)

I implemented the association by has_many and belongs_to methods. So I can have user's projects by `User.find(1).Projects`

now I don't know how to solve this question "user can see his projects and all public ones" by using scope methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
@user_private_projects = User.find(1).projects.where(public: false) #lowercase 'p'
@public_projects = Project.where(public: true)
```

The where clauses can be moved into class scopes:

- user.rb

  `scope: :private_projects, -> { projects.private }`
- project.rb

  `scope: :private, -> { where(public: false) }`

  `scope: :public, -> { where(public: true) }`

and then call: `User.find(1).private_projects` and `Project.public`

Comment: by using that I have conflict between current projects and publics project I can solve it by uniq method but do you think this is the best practice of doing that ?

Comment: One will return the user's private projects, the other will be all public projects. I'm not sure I'm seeing the same overlap as you unless a project can be both public and private at the same time.